# How to solve this integral with exp?

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is the question: how to solve this integral
$$\int_{-2}^{2}e^{-x^2/2-j{\cdot}x}dx$$; Here, j=$\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: is $j=\sqrt{-1}$ not that it matters much..can you complete the square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question lets complete the square as follows
$$
-\frac{x^2}{2} - jx = -\frac{\left(x^2 + 2j x\right)}{2} = -\frac{(x+j)^2 -(j^2)}{2}
$$
Thus the integral becomes
$$
\int_{-2}^2 \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(x+j)^2}{2}}\mathrm{e}^{-{1 \over 2}}dx
$$
Now using
$$
\sqrt{\pi}\mathrm{erf}(x) = \int_{-x}^x \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt
$$
We are done.

Comment: What is $\text{erf}$?

Comment: @user477343 It is the error function.

Comment: Thanks for that :)